# Can't scroll in Javascript when using jScrollPane

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, jscrollpane, composite-component, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm trying use JScrollPane to simplify the implementation of table scroll of my application. Some tables are so huge, this way, I'm implementing a dynamic load of the elements of the table. The loading is working correctly, however, when the table is loaded withe the new elements, the method scrollToY(int) isn't working:

```
Scroll = {

init: function (idComponente, componenteAAtualizar, comando) {
    var componente = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(idComponente));
    componente.container = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(idComponente + ":container"));
    componente.idComponenteAAtualizar = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(componenteAAtualizar);
    componente.desativado = false;;
    componente.posicao=0;
    componente.comando = comando;

    componente.container[0].oncomplete = function (xhr, status, args) {
        var idEscapadoPainelLista = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(idComponente);
        if (args != null)
            componente.desativado = args.desativarLiveScroll;
        componente.adicionarListenerScroll();
    }

    componente.adicionarListenerScroll = function () {
        $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').jScrollPane();
        $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').data('jsp').scrollToY(componente.posicao);
        $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').bind('jsp-scroll-y', componente.atualizarElementos);
    }

    componente.removerListenerScroll = function () {
        $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').unbind('jsp-scroll-y');
    }

    componente.atualizarElementos = function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
        if (!componente.desativado && isAtBottom){
            componente.posicao=scrollPositionY;
            componente.removerListenerScroll();
            comando();
        }
    };

    componente.adicionarListenerScroll();
}
};
```

Why I cant scroll to the position I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using JQuery to scroll to the position, instead of use scrollToY function of jScrollPane. So the code changed from this:

```
componente.adicionarListenerScroll = function () {
    $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').jScrollPane();
    $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').data('jsp').scrollToY(componente.posicao);
    $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').bind('jsp-scroll-y', componente.atualizarElementos);
}
```

to this:

```
componente.adicionarListenerScroll = function () {
        $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').scrollTop(componente.posicao);
        $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').jScrollPane();
        $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').bind('jsp-scroll-y', componente.atualizarElementos);
}
```